# Adaptar imagenes en un UIImageView en Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

estoy desdarrollando una app que funciona como lector rss, al leer la información de un xml, obtengo el titulo de la noticia, la fecha, y una imagen,
la imagen la obtengo con el siguiente código:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell")!
let imageView: UIImageView? = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView?

let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string:currentArticleToDisplay.imagen)
let imageRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response, data, error) in
     actualImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
})
```

He añadido una constraint para que la imagen me ocupe el ancho de la pantalla, pero como puedo hacer para que me salga la imagen con el ancho completo, pero sin cortar la imagen, ya que como lo tengo ahora, me sale la imagen pero cortada al tamaño de la pantalla. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar la propiedad `.contentMode` del `UIImageView` para ajustar la imagen como mejor te vaya.
Probablemente, deberás usar alguno de los siguientes tipos:

```
.ScaleToFill
.ScaleAspectFit
.ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: Si pongo esto: `imageView?.contentMode.` solamente me aparecen las propiedades `rawValue` y `hashValue`

Comment: He añadido esto `actualImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill` con lo que me has pasado y funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!